# Targetting a form NAME using javascript within Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the following form element:

```
<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" />
```

Which displays an empty text box on the page. I am using the following javascript to try and change the subject to the page's name:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='your-subject']").val('<?php stripslashes(the_title()) ?>');
});
```

When I view the source, the jvascript is picking up the title from the post as I can see it in the .val(' line, however the text box remains empty.

Can anyone advise why this is happening?
Thanks :)

Comment: Is there some particular reason you don't want to give an ID or unique class to the input element and target it that way?  It's very easy to do so with CF7.

Comment: I hadn't realised it was so easy to do. Changed the code and it works. Many many thanks :)